# AngularJs: How to create a directive to replace innerText

Tags: php, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working in a project(online exam, a single page application) using `PHP+MySQL+AngularJs` which has one very important section i.e. "Add Question". Let us take as a example:

$simple_question = "A train running at the speed of 60 km/hr crosses a pole in 9 seconds. What is the length of the train?";

$programmimg_question = "[code]#include    int main(int argc, char **argv) {      printf("%c\n", **++argv);    return 0;   }[/code]";

So you can see that, I am adding `[code]....[/code]` whenever programming language question is getting inserted so that I can prettify the code while showing the question. I am using twitter bootstrap which has `<code>` tag to show code between them. So I want to create a directive which will replace the `[code]` to `<code>` and render as a HTML in the view.

here is my code in HTML

```
<div class="question-container">
   <code-highlighter> {{questionData.question}} </code-highlighter>
</div>
```

directive code(which is not working):

```
app.directive('codeHighlighter', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
        questions: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var html = element[0].outerHTML;
        var hasCodeElement = false;
        if(html.indexOf('[code]')!=-1) hasCodeElement = true;
        if(hasCodeElement) html = '<code>'+html+'</code>';
        var e = $compile(html)(scope);
        element.replaceWith(e);
    }
};
})
```

I am pretty new for creating a directive in angularjs, please give me some resource or link to achieve the above problem, Please help me to out of it.

Thanks, In advance.

Comment: what is `hasCodeElement`?

Comment: Oh, its just a boolean variable which contains `[code]` exists or not in question, I will update the code for you.

Comment: also need to clarify what the problems are. Approach seems sound. You could pass the original code in via scope instead of needing to pull from exisiting html

Comment: Actually I am not getting the innerHTML(renderd html, which can be a string question) and want to append the `<code>` tag if string has `[code]`.

Comment: I would pass that in through scope. Also `outerHtml` would worry me that you are getting the directive tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to `$compile` anything. Just set the elements HTML based on the assigned question-text, optionally replacing `[code]...[/code]` with `<code>...</code>`.

You can do it like this:

```
app.directive('question', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            text: '='
        },
        link: function questionPostLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var html = scope.text.replace(
                    /\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/g,
                    '<code>$1</code>');
            elem.html(html);
        }
    };
});
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
$scope.questions = [
    'This is a simple questions (without any [code]).',
    '[code]var str = \'This is a programming question.\';[/code]'
];

<question text="txt" ng-repeat="txt in questions"></question>
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Xew98/2/)**.

---

**UPDATE:**

In order to be able to render HTML elements inside `[code]...[/code]` as is, use the following linking function:

```
link: function questionPostLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
    // Here, I assume that programming questions
    // always begin with [code] and end with [/code]
    var isProgramming = progRE.test(scope.text);

    if (!isProgramming) {
        var html = scope.text;
        elem.html(html);
    } else {
        var text = scope.text.replace(progRE, '$1');
        elem.html('<code></code>');
        elem.children().text(text);
    }
}
```

---

See, also, this **[updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/Xew98/)**.

Comment: Thanks for the solution with very simple and useful demo, its really what I wanted. But please help me one more time. if the question has html tags like this `$scope.txt = '[code]<h1>Hello</h1>[/code]';` then  in this case its showing as Heading text, I don't want this to render as HTML which is inside `[code]`

Comment: It is slightly more complicated. To simplify things, what do we know about the format of the programming questions ? Are they always going to start with `[code]` and end with `[/code]` ? Could they also contain "normal" text as well (e.g. `<div>Please take a look at the code below<br />[code]var code = 'some' + 'code';[/code]`) ?

Comment: No, If normal text has html tags then it will be automatically rendered by the browser, I don't have problem with this, but if any html code is written between `[code]` then it should show as it is.

Comment: It there any other way to do this, because its breaking when I am adding `C Language` questions, the regex is not replacing the `[code]` to `<code>` eg: for c question 
`[code]
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c = 2 ^ 3;
    printf("%d\n", c);
}
[/code]`